# Why aren't my songs dowloading?

Tags: downloading, youtube, mp3

I use an Android phone, and I usually download songs by converting them from YouTube to mp3 through websites. This time, when I hit the download button, the downloading didn't start. It said "download paused", and when I hit resume, it disappeared. How can I fix it?

This is what it looks like:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different internet browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, but I must remember you that this kind of YouTube video downloading method isn't legal and you shouldn't use it, you may be downloading viruses and other harmful components in your device.

If it didn't solve your problem, then leave a comment in my answer and I'll find a way to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

After few days reseach, finally I found an app can download Youtube videos (up to 1080p), download mp3 from Youtube ( up to 180 kbps). It's named HBTube. You can download full version at [HBTube Online](https://hbtube.online/#eluid39a8eda2)

***Youtube while lock screen***

[image: Background function]

***Download Youtube videos all format***

[image: Download function]

Good luck!